# Monacaで既存のWEBサイトを読み込み表示をしたい

Tags: android, ios, monaca

Webサイト（Webシステム)の表示を
Monacaで行うには、iframeを使用して行うのが一般的なのでしょうか？

その場合は、naitiveでwebviewを使用する場合と同じように
native→html、html→nativeのようなやり取りは可能でしょうか？

良し悪しは別にして、
Nativeで開発予定だったのですが、スマホ用に開発したWebシステムを
ラップしてアプリとして出そうとなりました。

Answer (score 1):

[InAppBrowser](http://docs.monaca.mobi/2.9/ja/reference/phonegap_29/ja/inappbrowser/inappbrowser/)というのがあります。

> native→html、html→nativeのようなやり取りは可能でしょうか？

[addEventListener](http://docs.monaca.mobi/2.9/ja/reference/phonegap_29/ja/inappbrowser/inappbrowser/#addeventlistener-ja)
[executeScript](http://docs.monaca.mobi/2.9/ja/reference/phonegap_29/ja/inappbrowser/inappbrowser/#executescript-ja)
この辺りを利用すれば、同じようなことはできると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！調べてみます。